# How I Make a dynamic element in HTML based on response result?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, tags

I want to have a HTML page as what TFS has:

[image: TFS Query Builder]

As you see, the elements of html have been built dynamically. For example, if we select the title we will have a textbox in view, but if we select Work Item Type as field, will have a drop-down.
For this purpose I will send a JSON from server, including this Items:

- Field
- Operators
- TypeOfElement
- etc....
  For example:

  `{Field:"Title" , Operators:"['=','contains']" , TypeOfElement:"txt"}`
   `{Field:"Work Item Type" , Operators:"['=']" , TypeOfElement:"drp"}`

How can determine in HTML which type of input element should be shown to client based on `TypeOfElement` value?

**Update**:
part of sample HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            New Query Title:
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="definitionCtrl.Title">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
        Query Structure:
// according to a sample I Put it here but I really don't know if using a directive would be a good decision or not, since I use controller as and not $Scope 
        <div id="metaDataDiv" class="col-sm-10">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="definitionCtrl.save()">Save</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

and sample controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .lazy.controller('queryDefinitionCtrl', queryDefinitionCtrl);

queryDefinitionCtrl.$inject = ['MetaDataService'];

function queryDefinitionCtrl(MetaDataService) {
    /* jshint validthis:true */

    var vm = this;
    vm.Title = null;
    vm.metaData = [];

  //according to a sample code: BUT I DO NOT HAVE $SCOPE!! WHAT SHOULD I DO THEN?
    vm.addMetaDataControl= function () {
        var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('#metaDataDiv'));
        var appendHtml = $compile('<my-meta-data></my-meta-data>')($Scope);
        divElement.append(appendHtml);
    }

    vm.getAll = function () {
        vm.getMetaDataPromise = MetaDataService.getAll();
        vm.getMetaDataPromise
            .then(function (response) {
                vm.metaData = response.data.result;
            }, function (response) {
                var r = response;
                ngNotify.set('Some problems occurred!',
                {
                    type: 'error',
                    position: 'top',
                    sticky: false
                });
            });
    };


    vm.save = function () {
        };

    function activate() {
    }

    activate();
}
})();
```

**Update 2**: I tested using `this` Instead of $Scope   [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/a7E9sT?p=preview) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Show some piece of code!

Comment: You can't do this using plain HTML. You need javascript or jQuery. Specify which one you want.

Comment: Paste some of your HTML code, I may be of help